# Is it possible to change Android font in all apps?

Tags: root-access, fonts, motorola-moto-g

Is it possible to change the Android font in all apps, including the keyboard? I have successfully changed the system font, but here and there I find odd fonts, such as in Flipboard and on my keyboard, Fleksy. I have a rooted Moto G running SlimKat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about keyboard font but maybe you can change the font in apps. Check out this link - [Custom fonts in apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424165/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-android-application). And also this link - [Custom fonts in apps 2](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/set-different-font-for-each-android-app-perappfonts-xposed/).
Link 2 is from external site.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Izzy - Yeah but I don't want to write/copy/paste all the matter because it was a lengthy post.

Comment: I didn't write "copy-paste all", but *include the essential parts*, i.e. an abstract. Shouldn't be too hard for the second one, e.g.: "You can use the Xposed module *PerAppFonts-with-link* as described in {link-to-addictive}". Should the addictive page disappear, that leaves at least the link to PerAppsFonts (if *that* disappears, the solution is gone anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out suggestions. I'll follow these instructions from my next post onwards ;)

Comment: Anytime! We're kind of family here, helping each other to improve :) So why not applying them here as well? You can always [edit] your post :)